# Filtering a Panda DF based on two possible values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a df that looks like this:

```
Created UserID  Service
1/1/2016    a   CWS
1/2/2016    a   Other
3/5/2016    a   Drive
2/7/2017    b   Enhancement
... ... ...
```

I want to filter it based on values in the "Service" column for CWS and Drive. I did it like this:

```
df=df[(df.Service=="CWS") or (df.Service=="Drive")]
```

It's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `|` instead of `or`.

Comment: Us the `|` operator like `df=df[(df.Service=="CWS") | (df.Service=="Drive")]`

Answer (score 5):

Need bit wise comparing with `|` (`or`):

```
df=df[(df.Service=="CWS") | (df.Service=="Drive")]
```

Better is use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df=df[(df.Service.isin(["CWS", "Drive")]])
```

Or use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('Service=="CWS" | Service=="Drive"')
```

Or [`query` with `list`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#special-use-of-the-operator-with-list-objects):

```
df = df.query('Service== ["Other", "Drive"]')
```

---

```
print (df)
    Created UserID Service
1  1/2/2016      a   Other
2  3/5/2016      a   Drive
```

Comment: You're a legend. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottBoston - Sometimes yes, sometimes not... It depends... But I think in SO are more legend people (`unutbu`, `DSM`, `Jeff`, `EdChum`) but in my opinion they have not a lot of time... But I cannot forget for `piRSquared` and `MaxU` and `Psidom` - very good also... and later legend too.

Comment: It's been tagged [**Legendary**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary)... He is a legend :-)

Comment: Correct Syntax for isin method df=df[(df.Service.isin(["CWS", "Drive"]))]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas.Series.str.match`

```
df[df.Service.str.match('CWS|Drive')]

    Created UserID Service
0  1/1/2016      a     CWS
2  3/5/2016      a   Drive
```

---

**Other Flavors**
*For Fun!!*

**`numpy`**-fi

```
s = df.Service.values
c1 = s == 'CWS'
c2 = s == 'Drive'
df[c1 | c2]
```

**add `numexpr`**

```
import numexpr as ne

s = df.Service.values
c1 = s == 'CWS'
c2 = s == 'Drive'
df[ne.evaluate('c1 | c2')]
```

---

**Timing**
*`isin` is the winner!  `str.match` is the loser :-(*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Service=np.random.choice(['CWS', 'Drive', 'Other', 'Enhancement'], 100000)))

%timeit df[(df.Service == "CWS") | (df.Service == "Drive")]
%timeit df[df.Service.isin(["CWS", "Drive"])]
%timeit df.query('Service == "CWS" | Service == "Drive"')
%timeit df.query('Service == ["Other", "Drive"]')
%timeit df.query('Service in ["Other", "Drive"]') 
%timeit df[df.Service.str.match('CWS|Drive')]

100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.46 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.74 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.77 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop

%%timeit
s = df.Service.values
c1 = s == 'CWS'
c2 = s == 'Drive'
df[c1 | c2]

100 loops, best of 3: 5.47 ms per loop

%%timeit 
import numexpr as ne

s = df.Service.values
c1 = s == 'CWS'
c2 = s == 'Drive'
df[ne.evaluate('c1 | c2')]

100 loops, best of 3: 5.65 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the top answer has wrong syntax for isin method, and the edit queue is full:

> df=df[(df.Service.isin(["CWS", "Drive"]))]